# HTML Submit form with both empty field check and button hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with "required" fiels, so Chrome checks if all fields are pressed when submitting the form.

However I want to add some JS to the button but in this case, my actions there override the default browser behaviour to check the required fiels.

Is there a way to execute Javascript on the button click AFTER the browser has verified that all fields are filled, without doing that check manually?

Comment: You could use setTimeout?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to be able to submit `form` having an empty value at `input`; or check that `input` is valid, perform task, then submit `form`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure

like this :

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="return checkform()">
```

**JS**

```
function checkform()
{
   //Code here
   return true; //return false for cancel the submit
}
```

**Example**

```js
function checkform()
{
  if($("#name").val()!="John")
  {
    alert("checkform alert");
    return false;
  }
  alert("Ok");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="monform" onsubmit="return checkform()">
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This will be called no matter what; Where I want my JS function to be called only when the browser has verified that all the required entries are not empty.

Comment: Look at my example, there is no alert if field is empty else checkform is triggered

Comment: @Michael At original Question: _"HTML Submit form with both empty field check and button hiding"_ , _"Where I want my JS function to be called only when the browser has verified that all the required entries are not empty"_ Appear opposite requirements? What are you trying to achieve?